# how to assign different thicknesses to different lines/strokes within same GP objects

Tags: grease-pencil

When I create let´s say a face with one stroke for nose and another for mouth.
I would like to set different thicknesses to those strokes.
how to assign different thicknesses to lines within same GP objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to create a layer and assign a value for the stroke thickness (let's say 50) and then create a new layer with a different value (300 for exemple). 
the strokes in the first layer will be thinner than those in the second layer.

[image]